# Killing Netbeans

Tags: 14.04, netbeans, killall

Sometimes I have hanged `NetBeans` on my `Ubuntu` system. How to kill it?

```
aux |grep [n]etbeans
```

gives too much id's in order to find correct one.

```
killall java
```

kills other java applications, but not `NetBeans`.

How to kill `NetBeans 8.2` ?

Comment: Have you tried `pkill netbeans`?

Comment: @bc2946088, it's not called netbeans in your process manager.  It's called `java`, like he said.

Comment: Try `sudo pkill -f java`.  It usually takes care of hanging processes for me.

Comment: He didn't say that, actually.  He said there were too many ID's to find the correct one.  I understand if the application isn't called netbeans, but that isn't indicated. @anonymous2  Any case, the answer posted would work as it would find anything in the process containing netbeans, not just in the application name itself.

Answer (score 21):

You can use

```
pkill -f 'netbeans'
```

Tested it and it works.

`pkill --help` says this

```
$ pkill --help

Usage:
 pkill [options] <pattern>

Options:
 -<sig>, --signal <sig>    signal to send (either number or name)
 -e, --echo                display what is killed
 -c, --count               count of matching processes
 -f, --full                use full process name to match
...
```

You can even use regular expression to filter the process name that suits your specific needs.